# C++ class object creation with explicit constructor call

Tags: c++, object, creation

I know that creating an object will cause constructor to call. But when I create an object Class Obj(); neither constructor nor destructor is called.
For example, I have a class named Test:

```
Test t;      // This will cause the default constructor to call
Test t(abc); // This will cause the parametrized constructor to call
Test();      // This will cause the default constructor to call, an un-named object will be created and destroyed immediately.
Test t();    // What happens in this case? Neither constructor nor destructor is called. It seems like no object is created.
```

Comment: indeed no object is created. Suppose you want to declare a method called `t` that returns a `Test` and has no arguments: `Test t();` Thats what it is

Comment: Got it. Many thanks for making this clear (Y)

Answer (score 0):

`Test t();` Creates a [forward declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c) for a function named `t` which accepts no arguments, and returns an "object" with the `Test` type.

No instances of `Test` are created. To call the default constructor, Use either `Test t;` (As you mentioned) or `Test t{};`.